# How to Configure SBCL to Use More RAM When Started Through Emacs?

Tags: emacs, ram, sbcl

How can I configure SBCL so that it uses more memory than the default when I start it by using "M-x slime" in Emacs?

From what I've seen online, the answer appears to be to call SBCL, passing the argument "--dynamic-space-size <size in MB>".  Since I do not call SBCL directly, I do not know how to pass it arguments.

I am using GNU Emacs 22.3.1 and SBCL 1.0.48 on Windows 7.  I have no experience configuring either, so a novice's introduction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual way is to set the value of the variable `inferior-lisp-program` to the command you want executed, including any options you want to give. Don't have an emacs on me right now, but this might be enough:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl --dynamic-space-size 1024")
```

Comment: I replaced my previous (setq inferior-lisp-program ...) above from my .emacs file with your form above, and it worked.  When I set I changed the "1024" to "2048", though, SBCL crashed, saying the value was invalid.  Do you happen to know the range for this value?  And why can't I allocate 2 gigs if I want to? >_>

Comment: It looks like the user mode memory limit for a 32-bit process in Windows 7 is 2GB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx .  Dynamic-space-size is only part of the memory sbcl uses (though probably the largest), so 2GB of dynamic space size would put it over the 2GB limit.  Or maybe there's another reason.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using SLIME 1:20120420-2 on Debian squeeze. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181683/350713) by [Kilian Foth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259310/kilian-foth) does not work as of this version. I wrote to slime-devel and was told

> As long as you're not using slime-lisp-implementations in your
>   ~/.emacs, setting inferior-lisp-program should work.
>   If you're using slime-lisp-implementations, you have to modify
>   this variable because slime ignores inferior-lisp-program if
>   slime-lisp-implementations is not nil:

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations                                                                                                                                                   
      '((sbcl ("sbcl" "--dynamic-space-size" "1024"))))
```

So, if one wants to check what the value of `slime-lisp-implementations` is

> Just evaluate the variable `slime-lisp-implementations`, e.g. with M-x
>   eval-expression.  If it's nil or not bound then it will not be used.

As it turns out, the value of `slime-lisp-implementations` for me was

```
(("sbcl" ("sbcl")) ("clisp" ("clisp")) ("ecl" ("ecl")) ("cmucl" ("cmucl")))
```

So, I put the following in my `~/.emacs`

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations '(("sbcl" ("sbcl" "--dynamic-space-size" "1024")) ("clisp" ("clisp")) ("ecl" ("ecl")) ("cmucl" ("cmucl"))))
```

With regards to where this was set

> If you want to figure out who or what sets it's to the value it
>   has, also check /etc/emacs/site-lisp/ or /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/

In this version of SLIME, `slime-lisp-implementations` is set in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/slime.el`.

For documentation of `slime-lisp-implementations`, see the
[Slime Manual: 2.5.2 Multiple Lisps](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Multiple-Lisps.html)
or use M-x describe-variable.

All quotes above are from  the thread [setting heap size for SBCL for use with SLIME](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.slime.devel/10860)
 on slime-devel.

Comment: Although its old, just wanted to say that this is the method I needed to use today.  The first method didn't work for me.  Thanks for posting it.