# Optimization for accessing array in lisp

Tags: optimization, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am trying to learn how to make type declarations in lisp. I figured out that `aref` causes problems:

```
(defun getref (seq k)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
  (declare (type (vector fixnum *) seq) (type fixnum k))
  (aref seq k))
```

Compiled, it says:

```
; in: DEFUN GETREF
;     (AREF MORE-LISP::SEQ MORE-LISP::K)
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-REF ARRAY SB-INT:INDEX)
; 
; note: unable to
;   avoid runtime dispatch on array element type
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a (VECTOR FIXNUM), not a SIMPLE-ARRAY.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 1 note
```

And so in every other function, where I want to use aref (and I do, since I need adjustable vectors), this happens too. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a *problem* and not an *error*. It just an information (a *note*) from the SBCL compiler that it can't optimize the code better. The code will work just fine. You can safely ignore it.

If you can't use a simple vector (a one-dimensional simple array), then this is the price to pay for it: `aref` might be slightly slower.

Comment: You can also muffle the note with `(declare (sb-ext:muffle-conditions sb-ext:compiler-note))`

Answer (score 5):

The optimization hint you get comes from the docstring of a `deftransform` defined in `sbcl/src/compiler/generic/vm-tran.lisp`:

```
(deftransform hairy-data-vector-ref ((array index) (simple-array t) *)
  "avoid runtime dispatch on array element type"
  ...)
```

It has a comment which says:

> ```
> This and the corresponding -SET transform work equally well on non-simple
> arrays, but after benchmarking (on x86), Nikodemus didn't find any cases
> where it actually helped with non-simple arrays -- to the contrary, it
> only made for bigger and up to 100% slower code.
> ```

The code for arrays is quite complex and it is hard to say why and how things are designed as they are. You should probably ask SBCL developers on `sbcl-help`. See [the mailing lists](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/mailman/) section on 
Sourceforge.

Currently it seems preferable to favor simple arrays if possible.

Comment: It's not an error message. It's just an optimization hint.

Comment: I was writing quickselect and quicksort, so i needed 3 vectors (lessers, equals, greaters) and a random element from some of them. I don't know, maybe I can somehow rewrite it. Lists are not a solution since random access for lists is slow.

Comment: And while it in fact works, on an array of 10^7 elements in range 10^9 I got heap exhausted sometimes

Comment: @AndrewS. (1) Shouldn't quicksort work with one mutable array and indices? (2) The heap has a limit, you can always find an example where you exhaust it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7181183/124319 to set the size.